# Not going to second page to extract data by scrapy

Tags: python-3.x

Saving data of one page and not going to second page and not showing any errors.

```
    import scrapy
    from ..items import QoutetutorialItem
    class QouteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'qoute'
        page_num =2;
        allowed_domains = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com']
        start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/']

        def parse(self, response):
            all_div_quote = response.css("div.quote")
            items = QoutetutorialItem()
            for x in all_div_quote:
                title = x.css("span.text::text").extract();
                author = x.css(".author::text").extract();
                tag = x.css(".tag::text").extract();
                items['title'] = title
                items['author'] = author
                items['tag'] = tag
                yield items
            next_page = 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/'+str(QouteSpider.page_num)+'/'

            # if next_page is not None:
            if QouteSpider.page_num <11:
                QouteSpider.page_num+=1
                yield response.follow(next_page  , callback= self.parse)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do that. Firstly, fetch next page URL from page source as it is present there and then make the request to that. This is how it will looks like.

```
next_page = response.css('.next ::attr(href)')

if next_page:  
   yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

This will solve your issue and now you also don't need calculation for next page URL also.

Comment: allowed_domains = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com'] Actually problem was there. It was solved when i removed http from the  allowed_domains. Thanks for your support sir